# How to Validate TextBox on client Side In asp.net without Clicking any button

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a problem in Validation form in Asp.net .
TextBox accept only interger values. if user enter any charater in textbox and sift control to next texbox error message show that only interger values accepted.

Comment: Use blur method

Comment: use validation controls.. see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery to validate input data

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  $("#test").keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
     {
        $("#err").html("Numbers only");
               return false;
    }
    else
    {
     $("#err").html("Looks good!").show();
               return true;
    }
   });
});
```

```css
#err
{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!--add Jquery withing head tag; -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

Number : <input type="text"  id="test" />&nbsp;
<!--validation message -->
<span id="err"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid integer Number")]
 public int Number { get; set; }
```

hope, this will work.

Comment: he said client side and this answer is server side!